# Using Spring Security with Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-batch

I have a Spring Service layer that is secured with `@PreAuthorize` annotation. So far this has been used through a web application. Now I need to enable our SpringBatch jobs to use these services.

What's the most straight-forward way to enable jobs to authorize them before calling these service methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, here is what I did to solve it :

In my tasklet, I called this method :

```
securityUtility.authenticateAs("login", "password");
```

Here is the definition of my authenticateAs method written in my SecurityUtility class injected in my tasklet, implementing ApplicationContextAware :

```
/**
 * Authenticate a user
 * @param username
 * @param password
 * @return
 */
public Authentication authenticateAs(String username, String password) {
    ProviderManager providerManager = (ProviderManager)applicationContext.getBean("authenticationManager");
    Authentication authentication = providerManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
    setAuthentication(authentication);
    return authentication;
}
```

It works well, let me know if you need more details ;)

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much the same way I ended up solving my problem, just a simple custom tasklet that does authenticating. Only annoying thing was that Spring Security seemed to have some dependency to Spring web, so I must include Spring web components to my build to avoid some warning about missing filters.